# How to create a private AKS cluster in an existing VNET using Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to provision a **private AKS cluster** using terraform. I want to connect my private AKS cluster to **an existing VNET** that I have created using the Azure portal.

The Virtual network option is available in the Azure portal. Please find the below image.

[image]

However, the terraform documentation on [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster) has very limited information on how to achieve that.

Please find my `main.tf` below

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes_cluster" {                                                                
  name                    = var.cluster_name                                                                                
  location                = var.location                                                                                    
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name                                                                         
  private_cluster_enabled = true                                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
  default_node_pool {                                                                                                       
    name           = "default"                                                                                              
    node_count     = var.node_count                                                                                         
    vm_size        = var.vm_size                                                                                            
    max_pods       = var.max_pods_count                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                            
  kube_dashboard {                                                                                                          
    enabled = true                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                            
  network_profile {                                                                                                         
    network_plugin = "azure"   
  }                                                                                             
}
```

**Please note that the VNET and the cluster that is to be created share the same location and resource group.**

Any help on how to provision a private AKS cluster to an existing VNET using Terraform would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used an existing code from Github with some changes as we already have vnet so instead of resource block I have used data block to get the details of the existing Vnet and instead of using the default subnet I created a subnet for aks and other one for firewall.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.50.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

#local vars

locals {
  environment     = "test"
  resource_group = "AKS-test"
  resource_group_location = "East US"
  name_prefix     = "private-aks"
  aks_node_prefix = ["10.3.1.0/24"]
  firewall_prefix = ["10.3.2.0/24"]
}

#Existing vnet with address space "10.3.0.0/16"
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "base" {
  name                = "existing-vnet"
  resource_group_name = "AKS-test"
}

#subnets

resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks" {
  name                 = "snet-${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group
  address_prefixes     = local.aks_node_prefix
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "firewall" {
  name                 = "AzureFirewallSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.name
  address_prefixes     = local.firewall_prefix
}

#user assigned identity

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "base" {
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group
  location            = local.resource_group_location
  name                = "mi-${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
}

#role assignment

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "base" {
  scope                = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/AKS-test"
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.principal_id
}

#route table

resource "azurerm_route_table" "base" {
  name                = "rt-${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
  location            = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group
}

#route 

resource "azurerm_route" "base" {
  name                   = "dg-${local.environment}"
  resource_group_name    = local.resource_group
  route_table_name       = azurerm_route_table.base.name
  address_prefix         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
  next_hop_in_ip_address = azurerm_firewall.base.ip_configuration.0.private_ip_address
}

#route table association

resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "base" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.aks.id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.base.id
}

#firewall

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "base" {
  name                = "pip-firewall"
  location            = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_firewall" "base" {
  name                = "fw-${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
  location            = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group

  ip_configuration {
    name                 = "ip-${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
    subnet_id            = azurerm_subnet.firewall.id
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.base.id
  }
}

#kubernetes_cluster

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "base" {
  name                    = "${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
  location                = local.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name     = local.resource_group
  dns_prefix              = "dns-${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
  private_cluster_enabled = true

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    outbound_type  = "userDefinedRouting"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name           = "default"
    node_count     = 1
    vm_size        = "Standard_D2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.aks.id
  }

  identity {
    type                      = "UserAssigned"
    user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.id
  }
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_route.base,
      azurerm_role_assignment.base
    ]
}
```

**Reference:** [Github](https://github.com/kuhlman-labs/terraform_azurerm_aks_private_cluster)

**Before Test:**

[image]

**Doing a terraform Plan on the above code:**

[image]

**After applying the code:**

[image]

**After the deployment :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me. In the `default_node_pool` block, I did the following:
`vnet_subnet_id = data.azurerm.mysubnetname.id`
Also, I used my existing subnet as a data source in my `main.tf`
After doing this, my private cluster was connected to the desired VNET. 
I wish the documentation said that the `resource id` of the subnet should be provided to the `vnet_subnet_id` argument. Thanks a bunch again :)

Comment: do u hv the syntax

Comment: @SatyamPandey, May i know what syntax you are looking for ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT, i have the existing vnet and subnet which i am using to create aks, i have used [link](https://github.com/kuhlman-labs/terraform_azurerm_aks_private_cluster/blob/main/main.tf) code, i am creating routetabel , route and doing routetabel association however getting below error '╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on network.tf line 41, in resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "base":
│   41:   subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.aks.id
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks" has not been declared in the root module.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT how would you run a kubernetes_namespace resource is same terraform plan so that it connects to the private cluster and creates a namespace?

Comment: Really great help author and
@pnkjkmr469 also your one comment helped me saving a lot of time. great help